# Can a variable that is I(0) also be I(1)?

Tags: time-series, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

After applying the ADF test for nonstationarity, I find that for both the test at level and the test at first differences, all my variables are both I(0) and I(1). I.e. the p-value is below 0.05 in both cases.

Is this an issue?

Comment: FenleyK, if you find the answer satisfactory, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer. Otherwise, let me know what is still unclear.

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

No, an I(0) variable cannot simultaneously be I(1).

The order of integration is defined as the number of differences that need to be taken to get rid of the unit roots. If the series has no unit root at levels, this number is zero. (The fact that you also reject a unit root at first differences is irrelevant then.)